# Migration to sonarqube 4.5.4 failed. Error updating database. Duplicate entry

Tags: migration, sonarqube

I have upgraded from 4.3.2 to 4.5.4 but during the database migration the attached exception occurs.

could someone help me?

best regards,
André

```
2015.07.17 18:59:58 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to upgrade database

### Error updating database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'fxcop-CallGCSuppressFinalizeCorrectly' for key 2
### The error may involve org.sonar.core.rule.RuleMapper.insert-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: insert into rules       (plugin_rule_key, plugin_name, description, description_format, status, name, plugin_config_key, priority, is_template, language, template_id,     characteristic_id, default_characteristic_id, remediation_function, default_remediation_function,     remediation_coeff, default_remediation_coeff, remediation_offset, default_remediation_offset,     effort_to_fix_description, tags, system_tags, note_data, note_user_login, note_created_at, note_updated_at,     created_at, updated_at)         values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,       ?, ?, ?, ?,       ?, ?, ?, ?,       ?, ?, ?, ?,       ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,       ?, ?, ?)
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry 'fxcop-CallGCSuppressFinalizeCorrectly' for key 2
    org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:26)
    ...
```

Comment: You should have a look at http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/Duplicate-entry-CallGCSuppressFinalizeCorrectly-fxcop-for-key-rules-plugin-key-and-name-td5025055.html

Answer (score 0):

You are using different plugins that are not compatible with each others. You should sort that out and you'll be able to migrate.

Here's what I suggest you:

- Install a local SonarQube 4.5.4 on your computer
- Using the Update Center, install all the compatible plugins that you want

  - => This way, you will be sure that you don't have any issue
- Then, copy this set of plugins from your local install to the server on which you are doing the migration, and everything should be fine